# En avoir (un grigri) dans le bide

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I*, le narrateur est en cellule :

> Sont tous fous d'amour-propre dehors ! pas à causer aux « hors les
> murs » ! **Ils ont tous un grigri dans le bide** qu'ils pensent qu'ils
> tomberont jamais !...

La phrase ci-dessus fait-elle référence à l'expression "en avoir dans le bide (être courageux)", ou *bide* doit être compris dans le sens argotique de "ventre" ?

Comment: avoir quelque chose qui porte bonheur "dans le ventre". avoir quelque chose dans le ventre est une expression idiomatique. Cad, en soi.  grigri est dans le cnrtl.

Comment: l'auteur a pris le parti de mal écrire, sans doute parce que sa pensée est confuse: Nous ne saurons donc jamais ce qu'il voulait dire, sauf à le lui demander, c'est là le charme de la mauvaise littérature...

Comment: @BBBreiz Pourquoi "mal écrire" et "mauvaise littérature" ? Merci pour votre brillante critique littèraire.

Comment: juste un exemple: "pas à causer aux "hors les murs": c'est du faux langage parlé, c'est aussi défaillant au point de vue du langage soutenu qu'au point de vue populaire, voilà pourquoi c'est mauvais. N'est pas Céline qui veut...

Comment: @BBBreiz C'est du faux langage parlé... ? J'aimerais bien lire vos romans à vous !

Comment: @Lambie Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Dès que j'aurai publié mon premier roman, je vous en enverrai un exemplaire dédicacé!

Comment: @BBBreiz Le Prix Goncourt, certainement !

Comment: J'ai déjà un début de dialogue, très original, du vrai langage parlé:
"Non mais t'as vu ça ! I' chante, et pis crac! un bourre-pif! Mais il est dingue, ce mec! Mais les dingues, moi, je les soigne! Je vais lui faire une ordonnance... et une sévère!"

Comment: @BBBreiz *N'est pas Céline qui veut.* Ben si, justement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce ***grigri** ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grigri)) dans le bide<sup>1</sup>* est une image signifiant que les personnes libres agissent comme si elles portaient en elles quelque chose, un porte-bonheur, qui les protège contre les coups du sort, spécialement ici contre l'incarcération.

<sup>1</sup> Dans le ventre ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bide))

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Alors, je pense que la traduction anglaise de ce passage n'est pas bonne : "They have a high opinion of themselves".

Comment: *High opinion of themselves* correspond à "Sont tous fous d'amour-propre".

Comment: Pardon ! "They all have a very high opinion of themselves outside! no point talking to any 'outside-the-wallers.' They all have a little amulet inside that thells them that they'll never fall!...."

Comment: Oui , une **amulette** !

Comment: Merci encore, jlliagre !